# Change image background for checkbox if is checked

Tags: html, css, image, checkbox, background

I am trying to implement this functionality, but when I click on checkbox (the checkbox is checked) then the checkbox doesn't change its background image and remaining as before.

How I am trying to do that:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input class="car_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
  <span class="private_zip"></span>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity:0;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + span.private_zip {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("checkbox.png") no-repeat;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span.private_zip {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("checkbox_check.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Why the image is not switched once is the checkbox clicked?

Thank you

Comment: That code would change the bg of the span not the checkbox as stated in your OP. JSFiddle please

Answer (score 0):

The last bit of your CSS should be:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("checkbox_check.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Remove the `+ span.private_zip` part.

Comment: Just to point it out, this won't work in all browsers. Dealing with inputs and styles is not easy.

Comment: Techically correct but I don't think we have the full story here.

Comment: I've tried to remove the span part, but still the same. This solution should work in IE8+ and the rest browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Read this

https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors

**UI element state pseudo-classes** section

I hope this will help